# Background image not covering td in Outlook 2018

Tags: html, css, email, background-image

I have background images in my email which I've configured using [bulletproof backgrounds](https://backgrounds.cm/). In Litmus, the previews look exactly how I want it to be for Outlook.

However, for the latest version of Office 365 ([Version 1808 - Build 10730.20102](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/monthly-channel-2018)), the background image doesn't cover the td's entire width?

**Preview**:

[image]

The dark blue-ish color is the fallback color, but for that specific Outlook version, the background image is not covering the entire `td`.

Unsure why this is?

**Code**:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- Condition to allow background images to work in Outlook -->
      <td style=" background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover; max-height: 384px; min-width:600px;" background="https://storage.pardot.com/213851/80721/email_insert_1.png" bgcolor="#1f3c5a" height="384px" width="600" valign="top">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px; height: 384px;">
                  <v:fill type="tile" src="https://storage.pardot.com/213851/80721/email_insert_1.png" color="#1f3c5a" />
                  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                  <![endif]-->
        <div style="min-height:300px;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
              <!-- Creating padding above nested div -->
              <tr>
                <td height="30" style="height:30px;">
                  <!--PADDING-->
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  </v:textbox>
                  </v:rect>
                  <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check again some changed.**

```html
<table bgcolor="#1f3c5a" style="vertical-align: top; background-position: top center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; max-height: 384px; width:600px;" background="https://storage.pardot.com/213851/80721/email_insert_1.png" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- Condition to allow background images to work in Outlook -->
      <td  height="384px" width="600" valign="top">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px; height: 384px;">
                  <v:fill type="tile" src="https://storage.pardot.com/213851/80721/email_insert_1.png" color="#1f3c5a" />
                  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                  <![endif]-->
        <div style="min-height:300px;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
              <!-- Creating padding above nested div -->
              <tr>
                <td height="30" style="height:30px;">
                  <!--PADDING-->
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  </v:textbox>
                  </v:rect>
                  <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Freddy if not working please drop comment into comment box i will more try to resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, unfortunately, my "master" wrapper table, which has the `tr` in is already set to `width:600px;` - `<table leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto; ">`

Comment: I think the issue is in the td, rather than the table width since the td width is loading (because the fallback colour is showing), just that the background image is not spanning the entire td for that one version of Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- Condition to allow background images to work in Outlook -->
      <td style=" background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover; max-height: 384px; min-width:600px;" background="https://storage.pardot.com/213851/80721/email_insert_1.png" bgcolor="#1f3c5a" height="384px" width="1000" valign="top">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px; height: 384px;">
                  <v:fill type="tile" src="https://storage.pardot.com/213851/80721/email_insert_1.png" color="#1f3c5a" />
                  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                  <![endif]-->
        <div style="min-height:300px;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
              <!-- Creating padding above nested div -->
              <tr>
                <td height="30" style="height:30px;">
                  <!--PADDING-->
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  </v:textbox>
                  </v:rect>
                  <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 Run code snipp
```

Comment: Please check the width of the image, What you have given in that code.